# Elasticseach, Type Properties vs Type Mappings, what's the difference?

Tags: types, elasticsearch, mappings

I would appreciate if someone could please help to understand what is the real difference between creating a type in the following two forms:

### Using “mappings”

*PUT  /mybestfares_test1*

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "bestfares_data": {
          "dynamic" : false,
            "properties": {
                "airline": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "null_value": "N/A"
                },
                "destinationAirport": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "null_value": "N/A"
                },
                "originAirport": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "null_value": "N/A"
                },
                "sellPrice": {
                    "type": "double",
                    "null_value": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Without using “Mappings”

PUT /mybestfares_test2/

```
{
    "bestfares_data": {
        "dynamic" : false,
        "properties": {
            "airline": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "null_value": "N/A"
            },
            "destinationAirport": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "null_value": "N/A"
            },
            "originAirport": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "null_value": "N/A"
            },
            "sellPrice": {
                "type": "double",
                "null_value": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I GET index information for both of these indexes, it’s clear that “mybestfares_test2” does not have any “mappings” definitions although there is a specific settings for each of the fields in the type:

GET /mybestfares_test2 =>

```
{
   "mybestfares_test2": {
      "mappings": {},
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1423741207570",
            "uuid": "ognGDfnTS7i9AVE1L66UgA",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1040299"
            },
            "bestfares_data": {
              "dynamic" : false,
               "properties": {
                  "destinationAirport": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "null_value": "N/A",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "sellPrice": {
                     "type": "double",
                     "null_value": "0"
                  },
                  "originAirport": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "null_value": "N/A",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "airline": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "null_value": "N/A",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

While of course the index created using  mappings has same settings about the fields within the mappings{...} section
*GET /mybestfares_test1*

```
{
   "mybestfares_test1": {
      "mappings": {
         "bestfares_data": {
          "dynamic" : false,
            "properties": {
               "airline": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "null_value": "N/A"
               },
               "destinationAirport": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "null_value": "N/A"
               },
               "originAirport": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "null_value": "N/A"
               },
               "sellPrice": {
                  "type": "double",
                  "null_value": 0
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1423741360578",
            "uuid": "rZ8wc2-2TGKVo8ZVd8YIKg",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "version": {
               "created": "1040299"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to understand what things (if any) will behave different between these 2 indexes?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the response, the second index that you create without the mapping actually gets a number of additional settings. So you do not provide a mappings in that case. So the first one is the only correct one.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look at this, I'm no sure to understand what you mean by "the only correct one".

Comment: Elasticsearch allows you to describe the elements in your type [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html) So, why did you say "this is not correct" ?
All I'm asking is what's the difference between using this approach instead of using explicit "mappings"

Comment: To my opinion, using mappings is the only appropriate way, providing it without "mapping" wil add something to the settings section that is not used and the mappings will use the dynamic mappings rules.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-mapping-introduction/ :

There are two ways of providing a mapping to Elasticsearch. The most common way is during index creation:

```
$ curl -XPOST ...:9200/my_index -d '{
    "settings" : {
        # .. index settings
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            # mapping for my_type
        }
    }
}'
```

Another way of providing the mapping is using the Put Mapping API.

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_mapping' -d '
{
    "my_type" : {
        # mapping for my_type
    }
}
'
```

This API enables us to update the mapping for an already existing index, but with some limitations with regards to potential conflicts. New mapping definitions can be added to the existing mapping, and existing types may have their configuration updated, but changing the types is considered a conflict and is not accepted. It is, however, possible to pass ignore_conflicts=true as a parameter to the Mapping API, but doing so does not guarantee producing the expected result, as already indexed documents are not re-indexed automatically with the new mapping.

Because of this, specifying the mapping during creation of the indexes is recommended over using the Put Mapping API in most cases.

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking at this.
I understand there are two options to add mappings, either at index creation or using the PUT Mapping API, but my question is not about that. My question is what's the difference between using mappings or defining the elements in your type without using mappings like I did when creating index mybestfares_test2 [Elasticsearch Object Type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html)

Comment: If that blog post is correct, I understood that there's no difference, except that the API also allows you to do it in a later time, although that isn't recommended. I'll also keep an eye on the thread for a better explanation =]

Comment: The link I provided is not from a "blog", is from the official elasticsearch reference guide :-)